# How to connect Remote RabbitMQ Server

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am going to build application (Asp.net C#) to connect RabbitMQ server  which is in another country.

So my question is how to connect that server.
I already installed RabbitMQ Client from NuGet Packages.

Is that needed to run RabbitMQ service in my local machine ?

Need to install RabbitMQ Server in my local machine?

From Client some of the parameters i got like
UserName, Password, HostName, Certificate with private key.

I am curious to know which are the basic steps to connect that server from my localhost application.

Can someone provide blog to refer ?
I already tried with different steps but not able to connect.

```
            string vCertSubjectName = "CN=DevRepo, OU=IT, O=OLX, L=KTM, S=Surrey, C=UK";
            ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            factory.AuthMechanisms = new AuthMechanismFactory[] { new ExternalMechanismFactory() };
            factory.HostName = "195.168.0.15";
            factory.Port = 5673;
            factory.Ssl.Certs = getCertificate(vCertSubjectName);
            factory.Ssl.ServerName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
            factory.Ssl.Enabled = true;
            factory.Ssl.Version = SslProtocols.Tls12;
            IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
```

Error coming like connection.start was never received, likely due to a network timeout."

Answer (score 2):

There are very good simple examples of how to write code to send and receive messages to/from RabbitMQ on their site.

Get those examples; set up a RabbitMQ server on your local network; build the examples and verify they work. Once you know how to send/receive to/from a known instance, you can change the connection properties in your send program to point it to the RabbitMQ instance elsewhere.

I would also suggest you do a ping to the IP address of the foreign RabbitMQ server to get an idea of actual transit times. That should give you some idea if the network timeout is a valid issue.

PS. You will need a valid login and password for the RabbitMQ server before it will accept any messages from you.  When you build the example programs above as long as you are on the same physical machine where RabbitMQ is running, you can use the default login and password of guest/guest.  By default this will NOT work from another machine due to default security configuration of RabbitMQ.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I also tried with set up server in my local network. and with guest user it is working fine. Change connection properties but didn't work for foreign server. They are providing me RabbitMQ cluster Endpoint. Is it used for rabbitMQ Hostname ? or it should be different ? might be needed more deep in security configuration.

Comment: For hostname I believe that is the server name which can be an IP address or the FQDN. You did not answer whether you have a valid login and password for their RabbitMQ server. Nothing will happen without that.

Comment: login and password for server is valid. Connection is successful with TCP Client but not connect with rabbitMQ client nor EasyNetQ.

Comment: Is this a "public" RabbitMQ installation? By that I mean, if I were to attempt to send messages, would they be accepted? If so, I could try given the appropriate ip, credentials, etc.

Comment: Thanks @john for explanation. issue is related to certificate file and it is resolved from client side.

Comment: @qadevrepublic001 can you provide details of your solution as an answer?